# Map with an inner stuct builder

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct, builder

I have a map with a inner sruct as:

```
struct Messages {
    unsigned int id;
    string user_name;
    string content;
    time_t timestamp;

    Messages(const string& a_user_name, const string& a_content) :
        user_name(a_user_name), content(a_content), id(++last_id)
    {
        timestamp = time(0);
    }
};

map<unsigned int, Messages> Global_messages;
```

When I try to access an element as:

```
cout << Global_messages[i].id;
```

It gives me an error about not having a suitable builder.

Comment: It would be helpful to get the exact error message and the map/struct init code. Also, is there a Global_messages[i] value?

Comment: I had already solved it ussing the default builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::map::operator[]` requires the value to be default constructible, which is not the case of `Messages`. You have to use other interface as `insert`/`emplace` to fill the map and `at`or `find` to retrieve value